# iOS app made with Flutter rejected due to unreproducible bug

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, release

My app was rejected by Apple because a feature doesn't work well on iPad (iOS 14.6).
I've reviewed the code and XCode settings and resubmitted several times, but the Apple reviewer says it still doesn't work on iPad.

The app is made with Flutter. The problematic feature is implemented with sqflite, which reads stored data from the local database.
In terms of the code, it seems that `snapshot.hasData` remains `false` in the `builder` property of `FutureBuilder` when it should be `true`.

However, it works fine when I did debug runs on the iPad/iPhone simulator. (I don't have an actual iPhone and iPad, so I cannot check with TestFlight)
The Android version of the app has already been released on the Google Play Store, and it works fine on Android devices.

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I doubt the following points;

- implementation of sqflite: do I need to implement something special for iOS?
- XCode signing and profile settings: I've set the target to iOS & iPad, and the certificate to "Apple Distribution", so it should be OK...
- To access the local storage of the iOS device, do I need to set some additional "capabilities" or something?

I'd like to know if anyone has encountered the same problem with Apple reviews, or if anyone knows more about it.

The output of the `flutter doctor -v` and the code where the bug occurs are as follows.

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.2.0, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /Users/xxx/development/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (2 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPad (8th generation) (mobile) • CA6F44F0-33C5-421B-A7D4-5A73832AE926 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                   • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77

• No issues found!
```

```dart
child: FutureBuilder(
  future: _itemList, // List that is loaded by databaseHelper's Read method
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),　// Apple reviewer says it shows infinately.
      );
    } else if (snapshot.data.length >= 1) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          return _buildItems(snapshot.data[index]); // This method returns the list of items.
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text('no data');
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: most likely `snapshot.hasError` is set to `true`

Comment: Is the data already added in the database? or is it added after an api fetch?

Comment: @pskink
Thank you. I added `if (snapshot.hasError) { return Text(snapshot.error.toString()); }` and resubmit to Apple to deconstruct this issue.

Comment: @DarShan The data already added in the DB when this feature is triggered.

Comment: could you post `_itemList` & db related methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help! This issue has been resolved.
The cause was that the path generated by `_initDb` method was wrong.

before:

```dart
Future<Database> _initDb() async {
  Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = dir.path +
      'items_table.db'; 
  final itemsDb =
      await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
  return itemsDb;
}
```

When `print(path);` at this point,
Android: `/data/user/0/com.example.app_name/app_flutteritems_table.db`
-> Although the path is incorrect, it works fine on actual Android devices.
iOS: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXX-XXXXX/Documentsitems_table.db`
-> This causes `DatabaseException(open_failed)` as an output in case of `snapshot.hasError == true`.

To fix this, modify the code so that the correct path is generated.
I added `/` before the String of database name.

```dart
Future<Database> _initDb() async {
  Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = dir.path +
      '/items_table.db'; 
  final itemsDb =
      await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
  return itemsDb;
}
```

Then, the correct path is generated.
Android: `/data/user/0/com.example.app_name/app_flutter/items_table.db`
iOS: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXX-XXXXX/Documents/items_table.db`